# How to parse Authorize.net payment response in Ionic / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I am getting a response from authorize.net payment gateway and tried many times and many ways to parse it but no luck.

> Here is the main response from authorize.net:

```
"{"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"1","authCode":"XXXXXX","avsResultCode":"Y","cvvResultCode":"P","cavvResultCode":"2","transId":"11111111111","refTransID":"","transHash":"","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXX0002","accountType":"AmericanExpress","messages":[{"code":"1","description":"This transaction has been approved."}],"transHashSha2":"2E6533BDC93C975EE3C1134B7421A337D5B8FB9C257437DB8B4XXXX4BCD92024B33704B811C69E58527359CA8628E8E33E55AA68B881E6F3D15B5F2FEAEB490B","SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0,"networkTransId":"HLH5UGDQFZ98LHRLDGIZEG7"},"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}"
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.onetruecode.com/integrate-authorize-net-in-ionic-3-app/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20authorize.net%20in,is%20a%20too%20sensitive%20phase.).

> I have tried this:

```
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.response));
console.log('1', result);
```

> And result is:

```
1 {"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"1","authCode":"9UQISS","avsResultCode":"Y","cvvResultCode":"P","cavvResultCode":"2","transId":"60164579108","refTransID":"","transHash":"","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXX0002","accountType":"AmericanExpress","messages":[{"code":"1","description":"This transaction has been approved."}],"transHashSha2":"2E6533BDC93C975EE3C1134B7421A337D5B8FB9C257437DB8B4DA924BCD92024B33704B811C69E58527359CA8628E8E33E55AA68B881E6F3D15B5F2FEAEB490B","SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0,"networkTransId":"HLH5UGDQFZ98LHRLDGIZEG7"},"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}
```

> I want result like this:

```
{
  "transactionResponse": {
    "responseCode": "1",
    "authCode": "XXXXXX",
    "avsResultCode": "Y",
    "cvvResultCode": "P",
    "cavvResultCode": "2",
    "transId": "11111111111",
    "refTransID": "",
    "transHash": "",
    "testRequest": "0",
    "accountNumber": "XXXX0002",
    "accountType": "AmericanExpress",
    "messages": [
      {
        "code": "1",
        "description": "This transaction has been approved."
      }
    ],
    "transHashSha2": "2E6533BDC93C975EE3C1134B7421A337D5B8FB9C257437DB8B4XXXX4BCD92024B33704B811C69E58527359CA8628E8E33E55AA68B881E6F3D15B5F2FEAEB490B",
    "SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator": 0,
    "networkTransId": "HLH5UGDQFZ98LHRLDGIZEG7"
  },
  "messages": {
    "resultCode": "Ok",
    "message": [
      {
        "code": "I00001",
        "text": "Successful."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please guide me...

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Please check the question I updated, I want some data from the response like 'transId' etc.

Comment: Does `console.log(result.transactionResponse.transId)` not work?

Comment: Got this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transId' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (checkout.page.ts:994)

Comment: Please provide the result of `console.log(res.response);`

Comment: It's in question

Comment: Not `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.response))`, but `res.response`.

Comment: I did not get it, what do I try?

Comment: I doubt `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are needed. So I ask you to provide the result of `console.log(res.response)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230211/discussion-between-user9088454-and-n-f).

Comment: I have done this or count it as Answer:  
console.log('API', res);
      var obj = eval("(" + res.response + ")");
      console.log(obj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Answer to my question:

I am getting this data in **res.response**:

```
"{"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"1","authCode":"XXXXXX","avsResultCode":"Y","cvvResultCode":"P","cavvResultCode":"2","transId":"11111111111","refTransID":"","transHash":"","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXX0002","accountType":"AmericanExpress","messages":[{"code":"1","description":"This transaction has been approved."}],"transHashSha2":"2E6533BDC93C975EE3C1134B7421A337D5B8FB9C257437DB8B4XXXX4BCD92024B33704B811C69E58527359CA8628E8E33E55AA68B881E6F3D15B5F2FEAEB490B","SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0,"networkTransId":"HLH5UGDQFZ98LHRLDGIZEG7"},"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}"

 console.log('API', res);
 var obj = eval("(" + res.response + ")");
 console.log(obj);
```

I solve the problem so I thought I should have to post answers it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

There's an NPM package "ngx-authorizenet"
It allows you initiate payment from Authorize.net using your Angular Tags.

```
//Set up your button in your view
<ngx-authorizenet [config]="authorizenetConfig" (responseHandler)="responseHandler($event)"></ngx-authorizenet>
```

```
//Import the module
import { NgxAuthorizenetModule } from 'ngx-authorizenet';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxAuthorizenetModule,
  ],
})
```

```
//YourComponent.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxAuthorizenetI } from 'ngx-authorizenet';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  public authorizenetConfig?: NgxAuthorizenetI;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initConfig();
  }

  private initConfig(): void {
    this.authorizenetConfig = {
      billingAddressOptions: '{"show":true, "required":false}',
      urlAction: 'https://api.yourdomain.com/authorizepay/callback',
      apiLoginID: 'XXXXXXX',
      clientKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      acceptUIFormBtnTxt: 'Pay Now',
      acceptUIFormHeaderTxt: 'Pay To My Account'
    }
  }

  public authorizeHandler(response) {
    //Visit Api Reference for API Schema
    if (response.messages.resultCode === "Error") {
      var i = 0;
      while (i < response.messages.message.length) {
        console.log(
          response.messages.message[i].code + ": " +
          response.messages.message[i].text
        );
        i = i + 1;
      };

    }
    else {
      performServerSideTransationRequest(response);
    }

  }
```

Then setup your action handlers and configurations in your controller class above: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-authorizenet?activeTab=readme